# Incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Word

Tags: java, string, list, object

I know why the compatibility error occurs, but I want to know how you can add a String to an ArrayList of type < Word > which is a class in the program.

In OO principles, a "WordContainer" is a type of "Container", and it contains "Words", which is what I'm trying to implement here, but how do you add a String to a WordContainer that has a list of words of type Word?

```
public class Word {
  private String word;
  public String getWord() {
    return this.word;
  }
  public void setWord(String word) {
    this.word = word;
  }
  public Word() {
    this.word = "";
  }
}
```

Container class which contains a list of words that are of type Word:

```
import java.util.*;
public class WordContainer {
  private List < Word > words = new ArrayList < Word > ();
  public List < Word > getWords() {
    return this.words;
  }
  public void setWords(List < Word > words) {
    this.words = words;
  }

  public void addWord(Word word) {

    this.words.add(word);
  }

  public void display() {

    words.forEach((word) - > {
      System.out.println(word);
    });

  }

  public WordContainer() {


  }
}
```

Main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner naughty = new Scanner(System.in);
  WordContainer container1 = new WordContainer();


  while (true) {
    String nextLine = naughty.nextLine();
    if (nextLine.equals("")) {

      container1.display();
      System.exit(0);
    }

    container1.addWord(nextLine); // this bit doesn't work :(
  }


}
```

Comment: "*I want to know how you can add a String to an ArrayList of type `<Word>`*" -- You cannot.  The whole point of making the list of type `Word` is to keep things that are not `Word`s out of it.

Comment: You need to create a new `Word` object.

Comment: Do I need to create a word object in the main class in conjunction with a WordContainer Object? Many Thanks.

Comment: @azurefrog Oh right, how can I implement it as a solution? Many thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method add from your WordContainer class is expecting a Word as argument not a String so what you should do is

**in Main.java**

```
  container1.addWord(new Word(nextLine));
```

And define a constructor in your Word class that accepts a String

**In Word.java**

```
public Word(String word) {
    this.word = word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `addWord()` method expects a `Word` as parameter, but you were passing a `String` to it in this line:

```
container1.addWord(nextLine);
```

That's why you got the Exception: `Incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Word`

**Solution:**

It needs to be:

```
container1.addWord(new Word(nextLine));
```

And you need to implement a `constructor` with a `String` argument:

```
public Word(String word) {
    this.word = word;
}
```

**Alternative:**

Or you can keep your actual main class code and implement a method that accespts a `String` and add a new `Word`object to your list:

```
public void addWord(String text) {
    this.words.add(new Word(text));
}
```